# how can I subtract time from time for time remaining?

Tags: javascript, datetime, time, datediff

Using JavaScript, How can I subtract from HH:MM:SS?

For example, I have 12:54:45 and I want to subtract 11:35:53 for remaining time in 4732 seconds

Comment: Using Date functions : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var first = (new Date('Jan 01, 2000 12:54:45')).getTime();
var second = (new Date('Jan 01, 2000 11:35:53')).getTime(); 
var differenceInSeconds = (second - first) / 1000;
// 4732
```

I chose `2000-01-01` as the date, as it does not matter as long it is the same. We only want to calculate the difference.

Comment: I have both times as var a and var b but they are only HH:MM:SS so how can I turn them into what you did?

Comment: @Nouth Simply use string concatenation to insert the time.

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
(Date.parse('January 1, 1970 12:54:45') - Date.parse('January 1, 1970 11:35:53')) / 1000
```

Output is `4732`

Answer (score 1):

There are libraries that makes possible to manipulate dates in an easy way: [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) and [day.js](https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs/) are two examples of choice.

```
// moment.js example
moment()
  .add(7, 'days')
  .subtract(1, 'months')
  .year(2009)
  .hours(0)
  .minutes(0)
  .seconds(0);
```

[More...](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/)

```
// day.js example
dayjs().add(7, 'day');
```

[More...](https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs/blob/master/docs/en/API-reference.md#add-addvalue-number-unit-string)

Also, for seconds manipulation, [Unix time](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) can be useful. It allows to describe time as the number of seconds elapsed since 1st January 1970.