# calculate differences between two times and return in minutes using jQuery and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to calculate differences between two time eg(server time=04:30 pm and 
`<p id="orderTime">02:30 pm</p>`) and return it in minutes such as 90 minutes using jquery and javascript

Comment: I want to get value from <p></p> and calculate with server to get time in minutes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible duplicate of [Jquery time difference in hours from two fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883768/jquery-time-difference-in-hours-from-two-fields) or [how can I subtract time from time for time remaining?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256381/how-can-i-subtract-time-from-time-for-time-remaining/)

But,

adapt this to your needs

```
(Date.parse('January 1, 1971 16:46') - Date.parse('January 1, 1971 15:30')) / 60000
```

it returns `76`.

`January 1, 1971` is used for Date.parse to return a value because it just parses complete Dates (afaik) but since we want the difference of times it's alright.

Comment: Thanks max-m Finally I got it

Comment: +1 Nice..was struggling while working with `am/pm` times. This solved it